# How to differentiate a Parent Admin with the Child Admin in salesforce

Tags: community

I've came across with a strange scenario as follows:

Few Days back, I've signed up for a SF developer account in which I've created a child user with 'System Administrator' privileges.

Now, I'm unable to differentiate between Parent admin and child admin?

Is there a way to identify them

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Are you referring to manager field or role hierarchy?

Comment: It's not about manager field or role hierarchy prakash.Assume 2 users having system admin privileges(1st user has created 2nd user). How u can identify parent n child admin among them? Hope it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is any such feature. System admins can manage user records of other system admins.

Comment: If its a case of just 2 or 3 users (Admin) then you could just check the Created date and Last modified date or Modified by User to figure out who's the parent Admin.
Hope it helps you...!

Comment: No way other than by UserId. That said, you can also clone the Admin profile and create a Custom Admin Profile where one has more permissions than the other, etc if you want to and assign one user a different profile.